# Font issue with MT4 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, fonts

There was a post before about installing MetaTrader 4 on Ubuntu Answer to follow but was wondering if my issue is different. I did copy over the Wingding font to get the smiley face in the top right corner to show if the EA is running properly but there are 'boxes' beside each comment of the EA lines. I would rather not copy over all 250MB of fonts from my windows install over to Ubuntu if I don't have too if this is a font thing then do you know which other specific fonts are needed? if my issue is related to the mfc4* files I haven't copied over yet then I can do that easily enough. See picture showing the weird boxes. [Weird Boxes showing in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijWYf.jpg)

Follow the steps to fix the problem:

1.Install Wine if it's not already installed (you obviously have it installed if you are running MetaTrader):
sudo apt-get install wine

Once Wine is installed you need to configure it. This is pretty easy. As a normal user (Not Root!) run winecfg from a terminal and it should set itself up. If you want to do any more configuration or tweaking, have a look around the tabs, but for now I suggest keeping it as default.

2.From a valid windows installation, copy over all the fonts into your wine installation. It also assumes you told Ubuntu to mount your windows partition in /windows:

```
cp /windows/WINDOWS/Fonts/* ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/fonts/
```

3.Copy two needed DLL files from your valid windows installation:

```
cp /windows/WINDOWS/system32/mfc4* ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/
```

4.Download mt4setup.exe from your favorite broker.

5.Install MT4.

Comment: Have you posted the answer in your question? (would be better to seperate it out to a self-answered question...)

Comment: But I don't think this will fix my particular issue I'm having. Hoping someone would tell me to either copy the mfc48 files or one particular font instead of 250MB of fonts. Would save me some work.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but might help others. For smileys and some other symbols I think the needed font is called:

wingding.ttf

You can download all Windows fonts at: http://www.w7df.com/